# How can I generate response after insert query in wso2dss?

Tags: insert, response, wso2-data-services-server

I am using wso2dss.

I just insert one row.
Table has only one field and it is not the unique and it is not a key.
I can't use the "GenerateKeys" option.

However, I need to generate response after insert query is success in the wso2dss.

### I created table as below.

### create table SAMPLETABLE (My_VALUE VARCHAR (100));

```
<data name="MyTESTSERVICE">
    <config id="testconfig">
        <property name="username">sa</property>
        <property name="password">sa</property>
        <property name="url">jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;MODE=Oracle</property>
        <property name="driverClassName">org.h2.Driver</property>
    </config>
    <query id="insertMyValue" useConfig="testconfig">
        <sql>INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE (My_VALUE) VALUES (:MyValue)</sql>
        <param name="MyValue" sqlType="STRING"/>
    </query>
    <operation name="insertOP">
        <call-query href="insertMyValue">
            <with-param name="MyValue" query-param="MyValue"/>
        </call-query>
    </operation>
</data>
```

It was working without any response. 
But I need customized response after inserting is successful. How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try stored procedures that return value. ie you can write sp which is insert values in database and returns the status of transaction, in dss it returns that whether your query ran on DB or not.

Comment: Is there any sample? In fact, I hope run it without any addition job in DB. When I tried to use H2, then, I can get return. But when I tried to use Oracle, then it has no return and error happened